# HBase prefixFilter works with startRow and PageFilter

Tags: java, hbase, row-key

In Hbase, I have rowkey like this : userId:timestamp:objectId.
I'm trying to create a method like this:

```
public List<Object> getObjectList(String userId, String startrowA, int limit)
```

I want to get records with prefix userId, and also have paging(startrow+limit).

So how I use prefixFilter, pageFilter to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try using the `FilterList` class and add to it a few filters that collectively will allow you to achieve what you are looking for. Try adding the following filters to your `FilterList`:

`KeyOnlyFilter()`: only scan rows, not columns (to make it faster)

`FirstKeyOnlyFilter()`: same as above, use both of them

`PrefixFilter(prefix)`: that's your prefix

`PageFilter(N)`: return only N rows

Also, make sure to set the right condition setting (i.e. whether all these conditions should be met or some of them). To make all of them meet, use `FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL`